# $().ajax events problem

Tags: jquery

I've a page with many textboxes. each textbox has a separated id and submit button. when users change a textbox and click on it's submit button, we update just that textbox with ajax. (in this ajax process button disappeared and textbox disabled.. and loading gif appeared.)
Now, the problem is:
when user change first textbox and click on it's submit button all things are working perfect! but when user clicks on second button, both buttons has been disappeared!! and if you continue updating.. all buttons disappeared and appeared!!
my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function iajax(obj)
{( function($){ //jQuery GAURD
    var p = obj.getAttribute('id',2);
    var itemid = p.substring(6); // find btn id
    var val = $("#txtTags"+itemid).val();

    $("#tagsup"+itemid).ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#tagsup"+itemid).hide();
        $("#msg"+itemid).empty().html("<img src='./images/admin_uploading.gif'/>");
        $("#txtTags"+itemid).attr("disabled","disabled");
    });

    $("#msg"+itemid).ajaxSuccess(function(){
        $(this).remove(":first").html("<span>Success..</span>").fadeOut(5000); // remove loading image
    });

    $("#tagsup"+itemid).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#tagsup"+itemid).show(); // show submit btn      
        $("#txtTags"+itemid).removeAttr("disabled"); // Enable txt
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "proc.php",
        data: "val="+ val,
        async:false,
        cache: false,
        Error: function(){ $("#msg"+itemid).append("<span>Failed!</span>").fadeOut(5000); }     
    });
    return false;
}) ( jQuery );
}
</script>
```

Body is like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="txtTags7332" width="200px" />
    <input type="button" onclick="iajax(this)" value="up" class="button" id="tagsup7332" />
    <div id="msg7332" style="float:left"></div>             
</div>
```

can you help me.. where is the problem?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this behavior because each time you click on a submit button, you add a callback to the Ajax method.

Explanation. By doing this :

```
$("#tagsup"+itemid).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#tagsup"+itemid).hide();
    $("#msg"+itemid).empty().html("<img src='./images/admin_uploading.gif'/>");
    $("#txtTags"+itemid).attr("disabled","disabled");
});

$("#msg"+itemid).ajaxSuccess(function(){
    $(this).remove(":first").html("<span>Success..</span>").fadeOut(5000); // remove loading image
});

$("#tagsup"+itemid).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#tagsup"+itemid).show(); // show submit btn      
    $("#txtTags"+itemid).removeAttr("disabled"); // Enable txt
});
```

each time you enter the function, you add a callback to the success, start & complete method... So, they are called every time you enter in this function.

Example:

- you get in with ID1, you add
  callbacks for the ID1.
- you get in with ID2, you add callbacks for the ID2. But ID1 is
  still present.
- you get in with ID2, you add callbacks for the ID3. But ID1 & ID2
  are still present.
- and so on...

So, why don't do directly :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "proc.php",
    data: "val=" + val,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings)
    {
        $("#tagsup"+itemid).hide();
        $("#msg"+itemid).empty().html("<img src='./images/admin_uploading.gif'/>");
        $("#txtTags"+itemid).attr("disabled","disabled");
    },
    success: function()
    {
        $(this).remove(":first").html("<span>Success..</span>").fadeOut(5000); // remove loading image
    },
    error: function()
    { 
        $("#msg"+itemid).append("<span>Failed!</span>").fadeOut(5000);
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        $("#tagsup"+itemid).show(); // show submit btn      
        $("#txtTags"+itemid).removeAttr("disabled"); // Enable txt
    }
});
```

?